# How to graph correctly with chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Well I'm graphing a table with chart.js, the problem that was presented to me was that when they were multiaxis the data was grouped in a bad way and it showed only one line, I already solved that.

What happens to me now is that in cases where the values are equal, it only shows the first value and does not fill the table well.

```js
const pivotBy = (data, groupby) => {
  let uniqueKeys = [];

  uniqueKeys = data.reduce((uniqueValues, obj) => {
    if (!uniqueValues.includes(obj[groupby])) {
      uniqueValues.push(obj[groupby]);
    }
    return uniqueValues;
  }, []);

  return uniqueKeys;
};

let data = [{
    "28": 483.00,
    "29": 481.00,
    "30": 486.00,
    "fecha": 1621915200000
  },
  {
    "28": 483.00,
    "29": 481.00,
    "30": 486.00,
    "fecha": 1622001600000
  },
  {
    "28": 483.00,
    "29": 481.00,
    "30": 486.00,
    "fecha": 1622088000000
  },
  {
    "28": 483.00,
    "29": 481.00,
    "30": 486.00,
    "fecha": 1622174400000
  },

];

let keyTemporales = []
data.forEach((obj) => {
  keyTemporales = keyTemporales.concat(Object.keys(obj).filter((item) => keyTemporales.indexOf(item) < 0));
});
/* Esta sintaxis Object.keys(data[0])
 * Se basa en un supuesto, todos los objetos del array son iguales del array son iguales. Es decir
 * si en el primero viene dos códigos 18 y 51 no puede pasar que exista un objeto que tenga 18, 51 mas un numero distinto
 */
keyTemporales.forEach((key) => {
  console.log("Preparamos a imprimir los valores con el key: " + key);
  console.log(pivotBy(data, key));
});
```

[image: tabla]
[image]

This is the expected result

[image: ResultExpected]

Update, I add complete code with the logic of the graph

```js
public generateChart(type) {

    this.checkGrafico = '0';
    if (type == null || type == undefined) {
      type = 0;
    } else {
      this.grafico.destroy;
    }
    let labels = [];
    const setDatos = [];
    let label = [];

    const pivotBy = (data, groupby) => {
      let uniqueKeys = [];

      uniqueKeys = data.reduce((uniqueValues, obj) => {
        if (!uniqueValues.includes(obj[groupby])) {
          uniqueValues.push(obj[groupby]);
        }
        return uniqueValues;
      }, []);

      return uniqueKeys;
    };

    let data = this.listadoResultado;

    this.headerVariedades.forEach((item) => {
      label = item.pro_des;
    })

    let keyTemporales = []
    data.forEach((obj) => {
      keyTemporales = keyTemporales.concat(Object.keys(obj).filter((item) => keyTemporales.indexOf(item) < 0));
    });

    keyTemporales.forEach((key) => {
      console.log(key)
      if (key === 'fecha') {
        labels = pivotBy(data, key).map((value) => {
          return this.helpersService.transformDate(value, 'dd/MM/yyyy');
        });
        // } else if (key === 'semana') {
        //     labels = pivotBy(data, key).map((value) => {
        //         return ("Semana " + value['semana']);
        //     });
      } else if (key === 'mesTemporada') {
        labels = pivotBy(data, key).map((value) => {
          return value;
        });
      } else {
        const color = this.helpersService.randomColor();
        const obj = {
          label: label,
          fill: false,
          backgroundColor: color,
          borderColor: color,
          data: pivotBy(data, key),
        };
        setDatos.push(obj);
      }
    });

    this.datosGrafico = {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: setDatos,
    };

    this.titulos = this.titulosGrilla;

    // Configuraciones correspondientes al gráfico.
    this.opcionesGrafico = {
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      legend: {
        display: false,
      },
      elements: {
        line: {
          tension: 0,
        },
      },
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true,
          }
        }],
      },
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to start the `x` axis with `0`,
that is how its done:

**version 3.x**

```
options: {
    scales: {
        x: {
            beginAtZero: true
        }
    }
}
```

try to explore the documentation of charts js at:
[here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/#creating-a-chart)

Comment: What does that do specifically, because I think it doesn't work for me.

` this.opcionesGrafico = {
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            legend: {
                display: false,
            },
            elements: {
                line: {
                    tension: 0,
                },
            },
            scales: {
                x: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                },
            },
        };`

Comment: it actualy sets the graphs `x-axis` from `0` so what ever values are render it will render the values no manor what they are equal to each other.
to make it work, kindly go through the `charts js` documentation and implement the code version that spacifies your `charts js` version.

Comment: I understand perfectly, checking I have the version Chart.js v2.9.4

Comment: Adding what it says in the documentation, maintains the same behavior

`scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
            },`